# null log start inserting into database when asp.net application run, logging using log4net

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, adonetappender

i am using log4net for logging in asp.net application following the steps i followed so far

first i add log4net using nudget package manager then create a new config file name "log4net.config"

then add this `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config")]` to assembly file.

then in the log4net.config i configure like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4Net.Configuration, log4net"/>
  </configSections>              

  <log4net >
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <connectionString value="data source=datasourse;initial catalog=DBName;integrated security=false;persist security info=True;User ID=userID;Password=Password" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([JsonStringLog],[Date]) VALUES (@stringLog,@log_date)" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@stringLog" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{strngLog}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="filename" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="date: %date%newlineMessage: %property{CustomeErrorMessage}%newlineLocation: %property{stack}%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
      <!--<appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />-->
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

then in the controller class i create a logger object like this

```cs
private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(HomeController));
```

and use logger like this

```cs
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["propertyname"] = "hello";
logger.Debug("debug");
```

its logs the logging perfect but problem is that it insert null logs repeatedly when run the application like this way

[image]

and insert the same log multiple times.

can anyone guide what will be the cause of null log insertion repeatedly and same log insert multiple times?

Comment: Is  <conversionPattern value="%property{strngLog}" />  a typo or is the property really called strngLog ?

Comment: @sgmoore yes called like that log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["strngLog"] = "hello";